# How do I create a string of random values from a csv file in Jmeter?

Tags: string, csv, jmeter

Having a csv (+1K rows) and would like to create a string from it where both number of values added and the values are random. The "string" will later be used in a sql statement. Pseudo code below showing what I'm trying to do:

```
  list = read_csv_file()
  values_in_string = randint() 

  for x in (1,values_in_string): do
    string += list[randint(1,length(list)]
  done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the "string" using any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) code:

```
def list = new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines()

def values_in_string = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, 5) // replace 5 with the desired upper limit

def generated_value = new StringBuilder()

0.upto(values_in_string, {
    generated_value.append(list.get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, list.size())))
})

vars.put('string', generated_value.toString())
```

the generated value can be accessed as `${string}` later on where required.